# Rsync macOS to Synology stopped working

Tags: macos, rsync, synology

I use rsync to copy files from my Macbook to my Synology NAS. I've been doing this for a couple years now and never had any issues. The other day though, I upgraded the Synology to DSM 6.1.4-15127 Update 5, and now my rsync script (which I run on my Macbook) fails with this error message:

> Unable to negotiate with 192.168.178.52 port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
>   rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
>   rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]

I tried a bunch of things, like upgrading rsync on my Macbook, or adding a `-c` parameter to the rsync call naming each of the ciphers mentioned in the error message, but nothing has helped so far.

This is my script:

> FOLDER=2017
>
> rsync --iconv=UTF-8-MAC,UTF-8 --delete -av --exclude ".DS_Store" /Users/jqno/Pictures/$FOLDER jqno@dekluis:/volume1/photos/$FOLDER

How dow I make it work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `-e "ssh -c aes256-cbc"` to the rsync command does the trick:

> rsync -e "ssh -c aes256-cbc"--iconv=UTF-8-MAC,UTF-8 --delete -av --exclude ".DS_Store" /Users/jqno/Pictures/$FOLDER jqno@dekluis:/volume1/photos/$FOLDER